# Can't connect network, wired or wireless (win7)

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

After reset my laptop, I lost my network connection. Actually I can't even try to connect through wifi, because when I click wifi icon on the system tray nothing happened. Wifi list box doesn't show up. I also try to connect through ethernet cable, icon on the system tray appear like I am connected but still there was no connection.

- It's not a hardware problem, I can connect internet when boot my laptop with kali linux.

-I reinstalled network adapters, nothing changed.

Comment: We need more information to help you.  What do you mean by reset? Did you install the required drivers for your hardware in windows 7? What are your IP settings when you connect to Ethernet? When you are connected to Ethernet can you ping the router (local network) and then can you ping outside?

Comment: while I was playing insurgency(game) my laptop freeze. Then I reset my laptop by long pressing to power button :) All drivers installed. via ethernet or wifi I can't ping or connect my router.

Comment: Hmm that is very strange.  I'm not sure what it could be.  I would start with a shutdown of the computer, unplug from power supply, remove battery and hold down power button for 15 to 30 seconds.  Then plug back in, boot and try again.

Comment: But it's not a hardware problem. I can connect now with linux

Comment: If your postive its not hardware try a restore point in windows.  it makes no sense that it would be working and after cutting power to the machine that it stopped unless it is hardware or something became corrupt as a result (unlikely).

Comment: restore point solve the problem thank you very much. I almost format my computer :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows System Restore to restore back to a working restore point solved the problem.